# Easy way to show that $\lim_{N\to \infty }PV\int _{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\boldsymbol 1_{|x|\leq N}e^{-2\pi i(x-y)\alpha }}{x-y}dx=...$?

Tags: complex-analysis

$$\lim_{N\to \infty }PV\int _{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\boldsymbol 1_{\{|x|\leq N\}}e^{-2\pi i(x-y)\alpha }}{x-y}dx=(-2i)\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(2\pi x\alpha )}{x}dx\ \ ?$$

I recall that $$PV\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{f(x)}{x-y}dx=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{[y-\varepsilon,y+\varepsilon]^c}\frac{f(x)}{x-y}dx.$$

First can we permute $\lim_{N\to \infty }$ and $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}$ ? Then I tried using dominated convergence theorem, but doesn't work. Maybe using brute force, we can conclude, but any other method is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are free to assume $N>2|y|$, so:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}PV\int_{|x|\leq N}\frac{e^{-2\pi i\alpha(x-y)}}{x-y}\,dx &=&\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+}\left(\int_{-N-y}^{-\varepsilon}\frac{e^{-2\pi i\alpha x}}{x}\,dx+\int_{\varepsilon}^{N-y}\frac{e^{-2\pi i \alpha x}}{x}\,dx\right)\\&=&\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+}\left(\int_{-N-y}^{-N+y}\frac{e^{-2\pi i\alpha x}}{x}\,dx-2i\int_{\varepsilon}^{N-y}\frac{\sin(2\pi\alpha x)}{x}\,dx\right)\\&=&\color{red}{\int_{-N-y}^{-N+y}\frac{e^{-2\pi i\alpha x}}{x}\,dx}-\color{blue}{2i\int_{0}^{N-y}\frac{\sin(2\pi\alpha x)}{x}\,dx}\end{eqnarray*}$$
where the red integral is bounded by $\frac{2|y|}{N}$ in absolute value.
 By considering the limit as $N\to +\infty$ we get:

$$ \lim_{N\to +\infty}PV\int_{|x|\leq N}\frac{e^{-2\pi i\alpha(x-y)}}{x-y}\,dx = -2i\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(2\pi \alpha x)}{x}\,dx = \color{blue}{-2\pi i\, \text{sign}(\alpha)}.$$

Comment: how the $-\varepsilon$ became a $-N+y$ in the second equality ?

Comment: @idm: between the first and the second line, I splitted the integration range in a symmetric set with respect to the origin and a missing part (that is the interval between $-N-y$ and $-N+y$).

Comment: The fact that $N>2|y|$ is to assure that $[y-\varepsilon,y+\varepsilon]\subset [-N,N]$ ? If yes, we just need $N$ big enough to have $y\in ]-N,N[$ and $\varepsilon<\min\{|y+N|,|N-y|\}$, no ?

Comment: @idm: yes, that is the purpose of the initial assumption. Since we want the limit as $N\to +\infty$, we may assume $N\geq C|y|$ for any fixed positive constant $C$. I took $C=2$ just to be safe.